# Picking non-blocked music for a Youtube video: how do others do it?

Tags: copyright, youtube

I might have to start curating a Youtube channel for my company. As part of my job, I need to tell my editors which music tracks they can use or not to avoid being blocked by Youtube's ContentID. (we could limit ourselves to CC-licensed music, but that's... well, limiting). Now, I realize that my question is pretty similar to this one:

[How to find out if a soundtrack will be allowed by youtube or not?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28797/how-to-find-out-if-a-soundtrack-will-be-allowed-by-youtube-or-not/28798#28798)

And the answer there was "you can't really know in advance", but then I see videos like the ones in GoPro's channel, which do use copyrighted music, eg.:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhmzmOwkRuM

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1RlihA8Xq0

And I think: surely they didn't randomly try music by different bands until they found ones that pass the filter. They (at GoPro or similar big companies) must "know" beforehand that the music they are using is allowed by the copyright holders to be used on Youtube. So my question is: how do they know it?

(I realize that the answer could get into the realm of business agreements and dealmaking between say GoPro and such-and-such indie recording label, so I'd appreciate links and articles about that subject too. FWIW, I checked some of the bands used by GoPro in their videos, and *some* of them are Youtube Content Partners, but not all of them.)

**EDIT:** okay, buying licensed stock music seems to be a sensible solution... BUT, for the sake of curiosity, now I'm interested in knowing how that whole world of licensing deals with (for example) small indie bands works, because we *could* do something like that in our market. (I realize that it will be much harder to negotiate with a big established recording label). So if anyone has information (articles, etc.) about that, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, you would be much better off purchasing royalty free audio from places like AudioJungle. I can't speak for GoPro, but larger companies will often purchase licenses to use such audio. Instead of trying to skirt around ContentID and find tracks and aren't detected (yet), make the relatively small investment and you'll save yourself a lot of headache down the road.

Comment: Well, sure, but how can I be sure that said royalty free music won't be blocked by ContentID either? A while ago I used a royalty free track from FreeStockMusic.com, and Youtube blocked it, so it doesn't look like a bulletproof solution either.

Comment: When you purchase audio through marketplaces like AudioJungle, you get a license to use that in any videos you use. You may want to look into the terms of the FreeStockMusic.com website - it looks like somebody just went and registered the track using ContentID. There isn't any repository or library that's open to the public to check if tracks are blocked.

For your reference: http://support.envato.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/416/55/youtube-incorrectly-flagged-my-video-for-copyright-infringement-what-do-i-do